# Creating Excel button save as different folder and different name everytime

Tags: button, directory, save, filenames

I want to save an Excel file using a created button inside Excel to automatically save the file when pressed to a specific folder using cell E3 in conjunction with actual today's date as the file name. Including a prompt asking if you are sure you are done with the file.

I've tried to look on the internet and cannot find yet a specific example to my query. I am new to VBA. I can find one or the other of what I want to do, but I cannot make sense of how to combine them.